# Convert all XML dates in file to normal dates (dd-mm-yyyy)

Tags: xml

Hello dear Stack community

I used an app to create a calendar backup a long time ago but I'm now unable to recover the backup in that same app for some reason. So I now want to replace all the dates from the ''calendar.xml'' file to a more normal date format such as dd-mm-yyyy so I can search the text file quickly for a given day of the year. If anyone has an idea of a code that I run to accomplish that, it would be grandly appreciated. I attached the beginning of the xml file with the first 2 entries for reference.

Thank you in advance

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<root>
  <calendar_entry>
    <title>No school</title>
    <start_date>1364774400</start_date>
    <end_date>1364774405</end_date>
    <description></description>
    <time_zone>UTC</time_zone>
    <location></location>
    <rrule />
    <all_day>true</all_day>
  </calendar_entry>
  <calendar_entry>
    <title>No school</title>
    <start_date>1366934400</start_date>
    <end_date>1366934401</end_date>
    <description></description>
    <time_zone>UTC</time_zone>
    <location></location>
    <rrule />
    <all_day>true</all_day>
  </calendar_entry>
  ...
</root>
```

Comment: What are the corresponding correct dates for the examples?

Comment: Normal dates are ISO-8601 format. YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: What languages are you using?  There are lots of libraries that support xml.

Comment: It is better to use XSLT for the task.

Comment: Your date values don't look like dates.

Comment: Can't help without knowing what these dates represent. The numbers are too big to be Julian dates, and if they're calendar entries I would expect them to be date+time rather than date only. Note, dd-mm-yyyy might be "normal" in some countries, but it's much better to use the international format yyyy-mm-dd (a) to avoid ambiguity, and (b) to allow use of date/time libraries like XPath 2.0+.